# If $2^{2013}-2^{2012}-2^{2011}+2^{2010} = k \cdot 2^{2010}$, find $k$

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Hey this is just a question i was having fun with but couldnt solve for some reason. Would love if you can help me solve it thankyou!:

If $2^{2013}-2^{2012}-2^{2011}+2^{2010} = k\times2^{2010}$.  find k

Comment: This site uses [MathJax formatting of formulas](//math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). More tips [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959). *(from a bot)*

Comment: How do you do that? I really tried to put it in but i cant do it!

Comment: Follow the link given. Also, is this a question you came up with yourself?

Comment: No its from a website. I was just trying to have fun you know

Comment: Is the second $\ldots+2^{2011}$ a typo? It seems odd to include $\ldots-2^{2011}+2^{2011}$ when they cancel.

Comment: Its +2^2010 SOrry!!!!!!! Im really sorry

Comment: Have you tried dividing both sides by $2^{2010}$?

Comment: I did but it became off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is of course the option of simplifying via a calculator but if you want to do it by hand, first I would pull out the factor of $2^{2010}$ out of the left hand side to get
$$2^{2010}(2^3-2^2-2+1)=k\cdot 2^{2010}$$
Then simplify and divide both sides by $2^{2010}$ to get
$$\frac{2^{2010}\cdot 3}{2^{2010}}=k$$
Which yields
$$3=k$$

Comment: Is it 3 or 6? Cause other anwsers say otherwise Nevermind

Comment: Hah, I misread the problem; fixed now.

Comment: Other people getting 4 and 6. Are you sure this is right?

Comment: @ewrwr Yes you can check my work. I believe they read your question before you edited it.

Comment: It's 8 - 4 - 2 + 1.  Looks like 3 to me.

Comment: Oh im sorry for confusing everyone! Im really sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=2^{2010}$ and just bring down some of the exponents:
$$2^{2013}-2^{2012}-2^{2011}+2^{2011} = 8a - 4a -2a +a$$
$$= 3a = 3\times 2^{2010}$$

So $k=3$.

Answer (score 0):

The knowledge you want to use:

$$x^{a+b}=x^ax^b$$

Hence you should be able to write everything in multiple of $2^{2010}$, by manipulating the coefficients to get $k$

Solution:

$$2^{2013} - 2^{2012} - 2^{2011} + 2^{2011}\\
=2^3 \cdot 2^{2010} - 2^2 \cdot 2^{2010}
=6 \cdot 2^{2010}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$2^{x+2} - 2^{x+1} + 2^{x} = k\cdot 2^{x}$$

therefore

$$k = 2^{2} - 2^{1} + 1 = 3$$

Answer (score -1):

As originally written, the answer was 4

2^2013 -2^2012 -2^2011 +2^2011 = k * 2^2010

2^2013 -2^2012 (-2^2011 +2^2011) = k * 2^2010

2^2013 -2^2012 +0 = k * 2^2010

(2^2010 * 2^3) - (2^2010 * 2^2) = k * 2^2010

2^2010 (2^3 - 2^2)
------------------------- = k
2^2010

2^3 - 2^2 = k

8 - 4 = k

4 = k

---

Now, by the same reasoning, the answer becomes

8-4-2+1 = k

3 = k

Comment: 3 or 4 or 6? Im so confused

Comment: @ewrwr it is 3; many people had just read your question before you edited it